How to solve SCSS problem with top content (text) overflow?
I have included some text in the chunk-pin, and the top of the text is overflown. Below is my SCSS style sheet:
.chunk-page {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;

    .top-bar {
        width: 100vw;

        h1 {
            font-family: "Roboto Serif";
            text-align: justify;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
    }

    .chunk-board {
        width: 90vw;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;

        .chunk-pin {
            width: 30%;
            margin: 20px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            padding: 15px;
            font-family: "Roboto Serif";
            text-align: justify;
            font-size: 15px;
            background-color: white;
        }
    }
}

As adviced by other users while browsing through existing questions, I have set overflow: auto;, but the overflow problem remains.

If I understand your question correctly then you want to avoid text overflowing in tags with the "chunk-pin" class.
Here is a code example where I have achieved that.
The width of the "top-bar" and "chunk-board" class made text inside "chunk-pin" to overflow since the width was used.


.chunk-page {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
  .top-bar {
    //width: 100vw;   //commented out width here to make space for "chunk-pin" class.
    h1 {
      font-family: "Roboto Serif";
      text-align: justify;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
  }
  .chunk-board {
    width: 90vw;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    .chunk-pin {
      word-break: keep-all;
      //width: 30%;     //Commented out width here to make space for long text in "chunk-pin" class
      margin: 20px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      padding: 15px;
      font-family: "Roboto Serif";
      text-align: justify;
      font-size: 7px;
      background-color: white;
    }
  }
}
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chunk-page">
    <div class="top-bar">
      <h1>Your Title Here</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="chunk-board">
      <div class="chunk-pin">
        Pin Content 1
      </div>
      <div class="chunk-pin">
        Pin Content 2
      </div>
      <div class="chunk-pin">
        Pin Content 3 Pin Content 3 Pin Content 3 Pin Content 3 Pin Content 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>



